# Uniformly Elliptic operator question

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Given $$Lu=a_{ij}(x)D_{ij}u+b_i(x)D_iu+c(x)u$$ a partial differential operator $L$ is (uniformly) elliptic if there exists a constant $\theta>0$ such that $\sum_{i,j=1}^{\infty}a^{i,j}(x)\xi_{i}\xi_{j} \geq \theta|\xi|^{2}$

My question is: is every operator of the form $\Delta + k$ for $k$ real number uniformly elliptic (example: $\Delta f +3f=0$? My answer is yes, since the term acting on $f$ is not perturbing the principal part.) Can I apply maximum and minimum principles for these operators? thanks!

Comment: It seems that $\Delta + X$, where $X$ is a first order differential operator, is the most general uniformly elliptic operator on a compact manifold with boundary, since you can take $(a_{ij})$ to be the metric tensor (assuming $a_{ij}$ are, say, smooth). I think this has some conceptual benefit for integrations by parts formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to whether $\Delta +k$ is elliptic is yes because adding the $k$ doesn’t change the coefficients on the second order derivatives (and it is only in terms of these coefficients that ellipticity is defined).

The answer to your question about applying maximum principles is yes provided that $k\leqslant 0$. If $k>0$ then it doesn’t hold in general - think of eigenvalue problems. However, this can relaxed. For example, if $k<\lambda_1(\Omega)$ where $\lambda_1(\Omega)$ is the first Dirichlet eigenvalue of $-\Delta$ in $\Omega$ then the maximum principle holds in $\Omega$ or if $\Omega$ is very ‘thin’ (where ‘very’ is quantified in terms of how positive $k$ is) then the maximum principle also holds.